# Breaking the law

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

[image]

**Across**
2. Mary Jane is head over heels, pursuing pair of jazz musicians who play in a southern style (2,3)
5. A vote cast by the end of third round (6)
9. In Cabo, Peter missed out on short drive around a southern walkway (5)
11. A loud party has no end to tropical fruit (7)
12. Intellectually get the better of undressed, loud idiot (6)
14. First off, they created the Red Sea and the African Great Lakes (5)
15. Entertainer and former sportsman Derek entertaining spectators at the back (6)
17. Clay later left American R&B singer for female servant (4)
18. In the neighbourhood of this street stalks Freddy, orange monster covered in fur (4)
19. Garment worn by women where León is at, making the heart of men primarily amorous (8)
23. A representation of data's reported to describe piano parts (8)
24. Lioness scratching tail of pygmy antelope (4)
26. He and Shaq had a high-profile grudge, or "beef" (4)
29. "Right to be forgotten in magical land?" – Time to return to city in the real world (6)
31. Rose regularly plays on the outside in a careless manner (5)
32. They can be deadly as explorer's ship's circling Jamaica's coast (6)
33. Accelerate automobile in northeast Quebec, going in the opposite direction, scratching side of bumper (7)
34. Human-controlled robots foiled incomplete scheme (5)
35. In prison, I made cannibalistic killers administrative leaders – that's a howler (6)
36. Dirty secrets finally shown in the middle of engagement (5)

**Down**
1. Separated people finally get second places to live (10)
2. Setter trapped inside bustling bazar's thorned fences (7)
3. After long match, play's ending in not the best mood (5)
4. Australian comedian and actor who portrayed Ant-Man and Hulk (4,5)
6. Promised to marry after revolt at heart (5)
7. Tell story about person who completely abstains from intoxicating drink (6)
8. Electric automobile eliminating excessive intake, resulting in advantage (4)
10. Chesterfield cigarettes of anise extract (4)
13. Leftist crime is on the rise – it's sky high (10)
15. Juliett and assistant got to listen to State of the Union (9)
16. On the radio waves, he must work (4)
20. Russian historical novel ignored groundbreaking device (4)
21. Break the law with character at the bottom of society, getting loaded (7)
22. Temperature was made one degree in Eastwood Medical Centre (6)
25. Beatles' central member, singer Paul, making poetry (5)
27. English statistician's woollen cloth picked up (5)
28. Chief of production of Ceefax ignoring note (4)
30. Initially appearing as odourless liquid (4)

Comment: Thanks for continuously coming up with great cryptic crosswords -- even though I'm never able to solve them, I always enjoy reading through the clues and trying to anyways.

Comment: @Sensoray My pleasure, glad you like them!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The completed grid:

> [image]

Across

> 2. Mary Jane is head over heels, pursuing pair of jazz musicians who play in a southern style (2,3)
>  **ZZ TOP** ZZ (pair of "jazz") + TOP< (Mary Jane = pot = cannabis)
>
>  5. A vote cast by the end of third round (6)
>  **OVATED** AVOTE* + .D
>
>  9. In Cabo, Peter missed out on short drive around a southern walkway (5)
>  **PASEO** A S in PE(-dr)O ("Peter" as it is called in Cabo (Mexican city), thus Mexican Spanish) ("paseo" is a walkway/boulevard)
>
>  11. A loud party has no end to tropical fruit (7)
>  **AVOCADO** A VOCA(-.l) DO (party = "do")
>
>  12. Intellectually get the better of undressed, loud idiot (6)
>  **OUTWIT** .OU. + TWIT
>
>  14. First off, they created the Red Sea and the African Great Lakes (5)
>  **RIFTS** FIRST*
>
>  15. Entertainer and former sportsman Derek entertaining spectators at the back (6)
>  **JESTER** JE(.S)TER (Derek Jeter)
>
>  17. Clay later left American R&B singer for female servant (4)
>  **AYAH** A(-ali)YAH (Cassius Clay Jr., whose stage name is Muhammad Ali) (Aaliyah Dana Haughton, "Princess of R&B") ("ayah" = a maid who is a native of India)
>
>  18. In the neighbourhood of this street stalks Freddy, orange monster covered in fur (4)
>  **ELMO** ELM + O (Elm Street, Freddy Krueger)
>
>  19. Garment worn by women where León is at, making the heart of men primarily amorous (8)
>  **MAXICOAT** M(.e. -> A.)XICO + AT (León, Mexico)
>
>  23. A representation of data's reported to describe piano parts (8)
>  **AGRAFFES** "a graph's" homophone
>
>  24. Lioness scratching tail of pygmy antelope (4)
>  **NALA** N(-.y)ALA (nyala = type of antelope) (Nala from "The Lion King")
>
>  26. He and Shaq had a high-profile grudge, or "beef" (4)
>  **KOBE** double definition (Kobe beef) (although Wikipedia says that Kobe Bryant was indeed named after the beef :0 )
>
>  29. "Right to be forgotten in magical land?" – Time to return to city in the real world (6)
>  **TAINAN** (NA(-r)NIA + T)< (city in Taiwan)
>
>  31. Rose regularly plays on the outside in a careless manner (5)
>  **LAXLY** AXL in (.L.Y.) (Axl Rose)
>
>  32. They can be deadly as explorer's ship's circling Jamaica's coast (6)
>  **NINJAS** NIÑ(J.)A'S (Niña/La Niña, a ship used by Christopher Columbus)
>
>  33. Accelerate automobile in northeast Quebec, going in the opposite direction, scratching side of bumper (7)
>  **QUICKEN** (-b.)UICK in (NE Q)<
>
>  34. Human-controlled robots foiled incomplete scheme (5)
>  **MECHS** SCHEM(-e)*
>
>  35. In prison, I made cannibalistic killers administrative leaders – that's a howler (6)
>  **JACKAL** JA(i -> C. K. A.)L
>
>  36. Dirty secrets finally shown in the middle of engagement (5)
>  **DUSTY** DU(.S)TY

Down

> 1. Separated people finally get second places to live (10)
>  **APARTMENTS** APART + MEN + .T + S
>
>  2. Setter trapped inside bustling bazar's thorned fences (7)
>  **ZARIBAS** BAZ(I)ARS*
>
>  3. After long match, play's ending in not the best mood (5)
>  **TESTY** TEST + .Y  (long match = test match (series of championship cricket series) = test)
>
>  4. Australian comedian and actor who portrayed Ant-Man and Hulk (4,5)
>  **PAUL HOGAN** PAUL + HOGAN (Australian comedian = Paul Hogan, actor who portrayed Ant-Man = Paul Rudd, Hulk = Hulk Hogan (former wrestler))
>
>  6. Promised to marry after revolt at heart (5)
>  **VOWED** .VO. + WED
>
>  7. Tell story about person who completely abstains from intoxicating drink (6)
>  **TATTLE** TA(TT)LE (TT = "teetotaller")
>
>  8. Electric automobile eliminating excessive intake, resulting in advantage (4)
>  **EDGE** E + D(-od)GE (Dodge car brand) ("OD" = overdose)
>
>  10. Chesterfield cigarettes of anise extract (4)
>  **SOFA** ...S OF A... (Chesterfield sofa)
>
>  13. Leftist crime is on the rise – it's sky high (10)
>  **TROTSKYIST** TORT< + ITSSKY*
>
>  15. Juliett and assistant got to listen to State of the Union (9)
>  **JHARKHAND** J (HARK) HAND (Indian state)
>
>  16. On the radio waves, he must work (4)
>  **SERF** (surf = waves breaking on shore/reef)
>
>  20. Russian historical novel ignored groundbreaking device (4)
>  **IVAN** IVAN(-hoe)
>
>  21. Break the law with character at the bottom of society, getting loaded (7)
>  **WEALTHY** THELAW* + .Y
>
>  22. Temperature was made one degree in Eastwood Medical Centre (6)
>  **CLINIC** CLIN(t -> I C) (Clint Eastwood) (although "degree = Celsius" seems a bit indirect to me)
>
>  25. Beatles' central member, singer Paul, making poetry (5)
>  **TANKA** .T. + ANKA (Paul Anka) (Japanese poetry)
>
>  27. English statistician's woollen cloth picked up (5)
>  **BAYES** "baize" homophone
>
>  28. Chief of production of Ceefax ignoring note (4)
>  **EXEC** CEE(-fa)X*
>
>  30. Initially appearing as odourless liquid (4)
>  **AQUA** A. + QUA (qua = as (in the capacity (or character) of))

Comment: Hah, re: 26a it didn't even occur to me to check whether his first name has a Japanese origin. Oops!